# c# problem with form / tabcontrol redraw on maximize

Tags: c#, forms, redraw, tabpage

I have an app / form with a tabcontrol on it.
When I maximize my app, I see a redraw-bug - empty parts of the right area on the tabpage arent drawn correctly and show other weird stuff.
(It's just the background, the controls on the tabpage are okay)

I assume it must be a simple setting somewhere, but I can;t figure out what it is.
Any hints would be appreciated ! :)

Edit:
Screenshot of the problem here :
http://i48.tinypic.com/dm318p.png
Focus on the top right :)

Comment: Maybe a link to a screenshot would help...

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might try is to invalidate the whole form in your OnMaximize event handler.  It might be overkill, but might solve your problem.

Is your TabControl anchored or docked? That might make a difference as well.

Comment: it's anchored to all sides, not docked.

Answer (score 0):

What's the value of the Dock property on the tabcontrol? You also need to look at the same property on the controls inside the tabs.

**Edit**

Try to set docking to "fill"

Comment: It's anchored to top, bottom, left and right, so it should resize with the main form.
It's not anchored.

Comment: could you put it in a panel and set it to dock-fill? anchor the panel then.